# Sort an array of strings as if mid-string numbers are at the end of the string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, custom-sort

I have an array of values that I'd like to sort alphabetically, *but* with numbers sorted after characters.

For instance, given the following strings:

```
$array = [
    'Core 2 Duo',
    'Core Duo',
    'Core Quad',
    'Core 4 Quad'
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    'Core Duo',
    'Core 2 Duo',
    'Core Quad',
    'Core 4 Quad'
]
```

PHP's sort() function is not suitable because it puts the mid-string numbers first, like this:

```
[
    'Core 2 Duo',
    'Core 4 Quad',
    'Core Duo',
    'Core Quad'
]
```

Natural sorting returns the same results as regular sorting.

Is there any way to tell PHP something like, "If you encounter a number, sort it as if it comes at the end of the sting"?

Comment: You should try [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: Btw, there is no `Core 4 Quad`, but there is `Core 2 Quad`

Comment: This doesn't actually make sense, honestly. Why would `Core Quad` go between `Core 2 Duo` and `Core 4 Quad` if letters have a higher sort value than numbers? Can you provide a larger set with how you want it sorted so that a more generic algorithm can be determined?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that what you're after is a function that pushes all numeric elements of your strings to the back, e.g. "Core 2 Duo" => "Core Duo 2".

```
// moves numeric parts of the string to the back
function transform($s)
{
        $parts = explode(' ', $s);
        foreach (array_filter($parts, 'is_numeric') as $key => $value) {
                unset($parts[$key]);
                $parts[] = $value;
        }
        return join(' ', $parts);
}

// natural sort on transformed strings
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp(transform($a), transform($b));
}

$a = array('Core 2 Duo', 'Core Duo', 'Core Quad', 'Core 2 Quad');

usort($a, 'cmp');

print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
<?php

$array = array('Core 2 Duo', 'Core Duo', 'Core Quad', 'Core 4 Quad');

$tempArray = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $exp = explode(" ",$value); 
    if(count($exp)==3) {
        $tempArray[$key] = $exp[0]." ".$exp[2]." ".$exp[1];
    } else {
        $tempArray[$key] = $exp[0]." ".$exp[1]." "."-1";
    }
}

asort($tempArray);

$sortedArray = array();
foreach($tempArray as $key=>$value) {
    $sortedArray[] = $array[$key];
}

print_r($sortedArray);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core Duo
    [1] => Core 2 Duo
    [2] => Core Quad
    [3] => Core 4 Quad
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For reliability, use `preg_replace()` to move all of the numeric substrings to the back of the string, then use natural sorting inside of a `array_multisort()` call.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8RLh9))

```
$array = [
    'Core 2 Duo',
    'Core Duo',
    'Core Quad',
    'Core 12 Duo',
    'Core 11 Duo',
    'Core 102 Duo',
    'Core 1 Duo',
    'Core 2 Quad'
];

array_multisort(
    preg_replace('/( \d+)(.*)/', '$2$1', $array),
    SORT_NATURAL,
    $array
);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Core Duo',
  1 => 'Core 1 Duo',
  2 => 'Core 2 Duo',
  3 => 'Core 11 Duo',
  4 => 'Core 12 Duo',
  5 => 'Core 102 Duo',
  6 => 'Core Quad',
  7 => 'Core 2 Quad',
)
```